# Add Gallery - document.getElementById("").innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I’m actually doing a page using css and javascript but i have a problem. To change the page content I use the function of `javascript of: document.getElementById("").innerHTML.` 
With all the content of only html works ok. But when I replace in the “” an element that use a JGallery library of javascript don’t works. I add the library

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.ad-gallery.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ad-gallery.js"></script>
```

and it works ok because the gallery works in the body of the index page. However when I put the same content in the innerHTML is not working.

Really would appreciate any help or if someone could tell me what's going on.

Comment: Adding JS to innerhtml will not execute javascript. You need to look at the gallery and see how they create the ads. If they use document.write, you can replace document.write with your own function. Alternatively use an iFrame. Please give a link to the plugin you use

Comment: Do you have added a reference to jQuery in your page?

Answer (score 0):

Content loaded by innerHTML or similar method is not evaluated, and so your script/style is never called (this method simply put the HTML in place, but AFTER the rendering)

There are some tricks to do it, but IMO it is generally a bad idea, deriving from a weird conception ; why do you need to do this ?

Comment: Usual reason. The ads are not in the place he wants.